# How can I binarize an SVG without grays into PNG

Tags: image, svg, png, imagemagick-convert, bmp

Well, I am converting an SVG with ImageMagick and the output always has grays because when I binarize the image always aren't black and white completely translated. Sorry, I explained worst ever...

I've tried to convert an SVG into PNG but I can't find an optimal threshold value. And I believe that's possible to change from SVG to PNG into a concrete size without grays because on browser I can see how SVG is renderized on zoom in/(out).

convert -scale 600x400! ../picture_1.svg ../pìcture_1.png

The error is even using other params for threshold and depth, the conversion isn't working completely well because some pixels maybe be black but are white...

Comment: You are not binarizing by your command. You are rasterizing. Binarizing means black and white only. You have just converted the vector image to raster. And you use the wrong syntax. It should be `convert -density XX ../picture_1.svg -scale 600x400! ../pìcture_1.png`. Proper syntax reads the image before any operators such as -scale. It always helps to post your input and output files. If you cannot post here, post to some free hosting service and put the URLs here. That way we can comment better or provide good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll see grays because of anti-aliasing. If a feature is partway on a pixel, it will color it grey to trick the eye into making the line look smoother than it is. It doesn't look like ImageMagick has a means to turn it off. What others have done is scale the output much larger, then use a "majority rules" or "nearest interpolate pixel" to scale down.

This might work, but it might need to be done in two steps with an intermediate.

```
convert -scale 6000x4000! ../picture_1.svg -scale 600x400! -interpolate nearest ../pìcture_1.png
```

Comment: This is not properly Imagemagick syntax. You need to read the input first. With vector files such as SVG, you need to use -density to rasterize at a high quality and then scale or resize down. So a better command would be `convert -density XX ../picture_1.svg -scale 600x400! ../pìcture_1.png`. Where XX might be 150 or 300.

Comment: I see a good idea on this answer. Maybe is not the perfect solution, but you teach me about which is the main way of doing conversion (anti-aliasing to trick the eye), so I give you the win because your risk was successful. But, you may use operation parameters after the input, as we learnt today :-)